# Meaning of these syntax (Pointer Arithmetic?)

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering what these 4 symbols mean. I am new to pointers in C and I'm not sure if this is considered pointer arithmetic?

```
1. (*x)++ 
2. *(x++) 
3. ++(*x)
4. *(++x)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `(*x)++` - Increment the value pointed by `x` (postincrement, returns the original value)
2. `*(x++)` - Increment `x` (post increment) dereference the original pointer).
3. `++(*x)` - Same as #1, but returns the incremented value.
4. `*(++x)` - Same as #2, but dereferencing the resulting pointer.

Also, #2 and #4 change the value of the pointer (pointer arithmetics), while #1 and #3 - change the value pointed by `x` (i.e.: whatever-x-points-at arithmetics).

Comment: 1 and 3 are not equivalent.  1 yields the current value of `*x` and, as a side effect, increments it.  3 is different in that it yields the incremented value of `*x`, not the original value.

Comment: You need to fix the numbering.

Comment: Actually, #2 (after you fix your numbering) dereferences what x was *before* it was incremented.  #4 does what you say (as it stands), dereferencing the already-incremented pointer.

Answer (score 5):

```
1. (*x)++
```

The value that is being pointed to by `x` is being post-incremented. This will yield the pointed to value prior to the increment operation.

```
2. *(x++)
```

The pointer `x` is being dereferenced and the post-incremented. This returns the value that is being pointed to by `x` prior to the increment operation.

```
3. ++(*x)
```

The value being pointed to by `x` is being pre-incremented. This will yield the pointed to value after the increment operation.

```
4. *(++x)
```

The pointer `x` is being dereferenced after being pre-incremented. This will yield the value of the location immediately after the one currently being pointed to by `x`.

Since 2 & 4 alter the value of `x` itself they are considered examples of pointer arithmetic. 1 & 3 modify the object being pointed to by `x`, but not the pointer itself; so these are not considered to be pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(*x)++` Increments the value pointed to by `x` and returns its *old* value.
2. `*(x++)` Changes `x` to point to the next memory address (Exactly where that is is determined by the size of what `x` is declared to be pointing at) and returns the value stored at the *old* address.
3. `++(*x)` Increments the value pointed to by `x` and returns its *new* value.
4. `*(++x)` Moves `x` to the next address (see 2), and returns the value stored at the *new* address.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that involves increasing or decreasing the value of a pointer (as opposed to the value of what it points to) is considered pointer arithmetic. Hence, 2 and 4 are examples of pointer arithmetic, while 1 and 3 are not.

For example, `(*x)++` means to first locate the value that `x` points to and then increment that value by 1, while `*(x++)` means to increment `x` itself (that is, make it point to the element to the immediate right of what it was originally pointing to), and then find the value of the element that `x` originally pointed to.